# Are relational integrity and referential integrity the same thing?

Tags: integrity, referential

I found the same definition for referential and relational integrity. Are they the same? I have researched the two terms separately but cannot find any good definitions.

Comment: I have never heard the term "relational integrity", only "referential integrity"

Comment: "I have researched the two terms separately" is contradicted by "cannot find any good definitions" since it is easy to find good definitions of "referential integrity". And what non-"good" definition attempts did you find? Where did you find "relational integrity" used? How was it defined there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same thing. The term "Referential Integrity" is used much more though.

Referential Integrity relates to Foreign Keys in a Relational DB. For a table to exhibit Referential Integrity, the Foreign Key must either be null or reference an existing PK value in the related table.

Comment: They are not the same. "Relational integrity" is not a common term but has an obvioius interpretation from its constituent terms--DB integrity in a relational DB. Referential integrity is a special case of DB integrity & has a particular meaning for a relational DB.